# Redirect HTTP and HTTPS properly in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect

`http://www2.mydomain.com/some-filename.php` to `http://newmydomain.com/some-filename.php` 
And
`https://www2.mydomain.com/some-filename.php` to `https://newmydomain.com/some-filename.php`

My "www2.mydomain.com" domain doesn't have the valid SSL, but still if the user access https then I need to redirect him to new domain with https only.

I have written the following code in `.htaccess` but it is redirecting to `HTTP` all the time.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>    

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www2\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newmydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2\.mydomain\.com$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newmydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</ifModule>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and what is the correct code to do this kind of redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking whether the incoming request is HTTPS or not. You can combine the two with a bit of clever regex grouping:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s (on:(s)|off:s)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%2://newmydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</ifModule>
```

There isn't an `%{HTTPS_HOST}` variable, as it's the "Host:" request field. All the `%{HTTP_(something)}` variables are request fields, e.g. `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}`, `%{HTTP_COOKIE}`, `%{HTTP_REFERER}`, are all request fields; `User-Agent:`, `Cookie:`, `Referer:`.

The second condition checks if the request is HTTPS or not, and if so (`on`), it captures the "s" which is backreferenced by `%2`, thus turning the redirect to `https://`, otherwise, just `http://`.

Comment: This is working well, but I have one more requirement which I just got to know, in which we nee to redirect some specific urls to different location on new domain. Such as `https://www2.mydomain.com/myapp` to `https://newmydomain.com/NEWmyapp` and some other like this. How to do this with current htaccess rule you suggested, or one way I found is copy the three lines and create it for all the specific urls? Please advise?

Comment: Done, I have added this rule `RewriteRule ^myapp/ /NEWmyapp/ [L,R=301]` above the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]` line and it is working. Is this right way?

Comment: @Prashant Yes, that's fine. If you have multiple redirects, you generally want the more specific ones above the more general ones.